# Retrieving data from database into grid view based on the selected date in calendar

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, calendar

I have a calendar and a grid view. I'm using SQL database and query is a view. There is a date column in the view and based on the date selected from the calendar I need to get the corresponding data(from view) in grid view. I'm having problem in SQLCOMMAND. Please help me.

Comment: what is ur date format that get from calendar?

Comment: showing some of your code would enable you to get help on this promptly rather than plain detail of what you are facing...